# Ring of processes using fork() and pipes

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I've been wracking my brain about this problem during an hour. I have to create a ring of processes with n processes (quantity is passed as an argument via cmd). The parent process sends his PID to his first child, and this one sends his parent's PID plus his own PID to his next brother, and it happens until we have created n children. After that, the parent process gets the addition of the PID of all his children.

Let's suppose that the parent process' PID is 3400 and we create two children, so the ring is made of three processes

3400 + 3401(first child's PID) + 3402(second child's PID) = 10203

The parent process should get this 10203.

I have thought about one "for" loop in which child processes send the addition of their brothers PID from brother to brother, using only one pipe. Nonetheless, I haven't come across a solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the task is to use `fork()` and `pipe()`, you probably need to use an algorithm like:

- Parent creates pipe for it to write to 1<sup>st</sup> child.
- Parent keeps open the write end of pipe to 1<sup>st</sup> child.
- Parent keeps open the read end of the pipe from N<sup>th</sup> child.
- For each child n = 1..N, Parent creates output pipe for n<sup>th</sup> child to talk to n+1<sup>th</sup>.
- Parent forks n<sup>th</sup> child.
- n<sup>th</sup> child closes the write end of its input pipe and the read end of its output pipe.
- n<sup>th</sup> child reads sum of PIDs from input pipe, adds its own pid to the sum, and writes that to the output pipe, then exits.
- Meanwhile, Parent closes both ends of the input pipe to the n<sup>th</sup> (except for the descriptors it must keep open), and loops back to create the n+1<sup>th</sup> child's pipe and then the child.
- When all the children have been launched, parent writes its PID to 1<sup>st</sup> child and closes the write end of that pipe.
- It then reads a response from the N<sup>th</sup> child, closes the read end of the pipe, and prints the result.

What is less obvious how you can validate the sum, unless each child also writes its PID to standard output, or the parent (which knows all the child PIDs) computes the answer to verify it.

---

With zero marks because of the complete lack of error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int N = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 10;
    int c1_wr;
    int cN_rd;
    int p1[2];
    int p2[2];
    int pid_chk = getpid();

    if (N <= 0 || N >= 100)
        N = 10;

    pipe(p1);
    c1_wr = dup(p1[1]);
    printf("%d children\n", N);
    printf("Parent   = %d\n", pid_chk);

    for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
    {
        int pid;
        pipe(p2);
        fflush(stdout);
        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            close(p1[1]);
            close(p2[0]);
            int pid_sum;
            read(p1[0], &pid_sum, sizeof(pid_sum));
            pid_sum += getpid();
            write(p2[1], &pid_sum, sizeof(pid_sum));
            close(p1[0]);
            close(p2[1]);
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("Child %2d = %d\n", n+1, pid);
        pid_chk += pid;
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p1[1]);
        p1[0] = p2[0];
        p1[1] = p2[1];
    }

    cN_rd = p2[0];
    close(p2[1]);

    int pid_sum = getpid();
    write(c1_wr, &pid_sum, sizeof(pid_sum));
    close(c1_wr);
    read(cN_rd, &pid_sum, sizeof(pid_sum));
    close(cN_rd);
    printf("PID sum = %d\n", pid_sum);
    printf("PID chk = %d\n", pid_chk);

    return 0;
}
```

Sample run:

```
10 children
Parent   = 49686
Child  1 = 49688
Child  2 = 49689
Child  3 = 49690
Child  4 = 49691
Child  5 = 49692
Child  6 = 49693
Child  7 = 49694
Child  8 = 49695
Child  9 = 49696
Child 10 = 49697
PID sum = 546611
PID chk = 546611
```

The purpose of the `fflush(stdout);` becomes clear if (a) you omit it and (b) you run the output through a pipeline.  It is necessary.

Comment: Good one! I created an example in which I use only one pipe, and I can make the addition too. Is that correct? Which advantadges offers the fact of using two pipes instead of one?

Comment: On one vs many: with the many pipes solution, you are guaranteed to sequence the data travelling in the correct sequence; with the one pipe solution, you are somewhat at the whim of the o/s scheduler as to what sequence the children read the data in.  You're probably safe enough, but if you printed out the PIDs of the processes as they read the value off the pipe, they might not be in monotonically increasing order.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of inter process communication (IPC). Commonly used methods for IPC are:

- loopback socket
- shared memory

You can find all the other methods in [wikipedia IPC article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: The task is to use pipes as the method of IPC.  I don't see how this helps answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in control of the behavior of the child processes, and the parent process doesn't have important/hard-to-recreate state before launching the children, you can simplify things.

Instead of an IPC, you can have the parent recursively launch the children detached, terminate itself, and have the last child re-start the parent:

1. Invoke `parent n`, where `n` is number of children to spawn.
2. `parent`:

   - invokes `child arg1-1 0` and terminates,
   - if invoked with `"0"` for `arg1`, it adds its own PID to `arg2` and you're done, even though in terms of the process tree it's not really a "parent" of anything.
3. `child`:

   - invokes `child arg-1 arg2+pid`, where `pid` is child's own PID.
   - if invoked with `"0"` for `arg1`, it invokes `parent 0 arg2+pid`.